# Set indexing python

Tags: python-3.x

Can we do indexing in a python set, to attain an element from a specific index?
Like accessing a certain element from the below set:

st = {'a', 'b', 'g'}

How to return the second element by indexing?

Comment: There are no indexes and no "second element" in a set.

Comment: `list(sorted(st))[1]`

Comment: set is unordered collection of immutable elements since you can not do indexing properly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  A set is unordered [by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @learner8269 's answer, if you just need the index of a particular element (for some unknown reasons of life), you can get it using enumerate().

```
ele = 4
s = set(range(2,10))
for i,j in enumerate(s):
    if j == ele:
        break
print('Index of %d: %d'%(ele,i))
```

Comment: This may give different answers every time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a subset using indexes. `set` is an unordered collection with non-duplicated items. The `set`'s `pop` method removes a random item from the `set`. So, it is impossible in general, but if you want to remove a limited number of random items (I can't imagine why anybody needs it), you can call `pop` multiple times in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have influence on the construction of the set, you can create a dictionary instead of that set where each value of the original set is the key to your index or vice versa whatever suits the need.

```
>>>{key:i for i,key in enumerate(st)}
{'g': 0, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>>{i:key for i,key in enumerate(st)}
{0: 'g', 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

Answer (score -5):

As set is un-ordered we need to work around to get what is expected. Following code would do the job:

```
mySet = set([1, 2, 3])
list(mySet)[0]
```

This create a new list which contains each member of the set, It won't be a good choice if your set is really large.

Comment: The return value of this method is not deterministic.